# Set Visibility after countdown ends

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

Despite thorough search of other user's questions, I don't seem to understand how to do a countdown timer. All I wanna do is setting visibility to GONE after 30 seconds without touching the screen. So far I've done this:

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                          //SET VISIBILITY TO VISIBLE
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                             //SET VISIBILITY TO GONE
            }
        }.start();


        cpHover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //Should I countDownTimer.start()? It says there's an error
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(textBox.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
                else if(textBox.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

The process should be quite easy. Setting in onCreate() a 30-second countdown that starts every time the user clicks cpHover. When they click it again, it should restart the countdown. There are two ways of hiding the UI: clicking on the screen when it's visible or not clicking at all in 30+ seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this inside your `onCreate()`

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
                //set visibility as gone here
                if(textBox.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
  }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Where should I put that? As a global variable? Inside onCreate()? Inside onClick()? Thank you.

Comment: inside oncreate

Answer (score 0):

Its very Simple, just change your code as per below :

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                      //SET VISIBILITY TO VISIBLE
           donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View. VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
                         //SET VISIBILITY TO GONE
            donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        }
    }.start();
```

you want to start `CountDownTimer` in Click event then add above code in the click event

Happy Coading....

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
                setUpCountDown();
                cpHover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    //Should I countDownTimer.start()? It says there's an error
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                      if(countDownTimer != null) {
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                      }
                      setUpCountDown();
                    }
                );
    }
    private void setUpCountDown() {
              countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                  //SET VISIBILITY TO VISIBLE
                          donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          textBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                            donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            textBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }.start();
    }
```